# Create a recursive function that takes a list and uses it to create a List

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am very new in haskell and functional programming.I am trying to creat a recursive function that takes a list and uses it to create a List in the following way:

```
function [3,4,2] = Cons 3 (Cons 4 (Cons 2 Nil))
```

This function will take a list and return it as Cons.I will very much appreciate help and explanation.

Comment: Please **1.** always add the definition for all nonstandard data types you're talking about (it's pretty obvious here what `Cons` and `Nil` are, but in general it might not be clear) **2.** show that you've actually tried to solve the task yourself, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Kaliba, I can tell you so much: your function will have two cases. One for the empty list, and one for any non-empty list. Please try to come up with the first case at least! (We know you're smart, as you use SO.)

Comment: follow this link:http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/lectures/tutorial6.html#@sli@39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving Show

function [] = Nil

function (x:xs) = Cons x (makeList xs)
```

Go to this link to learn related skills that you are lacking:http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/lectures/tutorial6.html#@sli@39